# Does core 2 duo E8200 Support 64bit windows?

Tags: 64-bit

**Yes as the title say, does core 2 duo E-8200 support 64-Bit windows?**

i am currently trying to find a core 2 duo E-8200 and i wanted to know if it's going to run on 64-Bit system or not.

Comment: To verify for yourself whether you can run Windows 10 64-bit you can run [coreinfo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/downloads/coreinfo) and verify that your system supports `PREFETCHW`, `LAHF-SAHF` and  `CX16/CMPXCHG16B` which are the mandatory "extra" features required by Windows 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Intel Ark site https://ark.intel.com/products/33909/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-E8200-6M-Cache-2_66-GHz-1333-MHz-FSB - yes it does 64-bit Instruction set. It can run 64 bit OS.